# How can I fill gaps at counter level for backsplash tile?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, tile, backsplash

My wife and I are tackling redoing a kitchen backsplash with mosaic tile. We first had to redo some drywall. In hindsight I would have done a few things differently but we’re here now. We have some small gaps between the counter level and drywall, and I was curious on how to fix or if the back splash would cover it

https://imgur.com/gallery/CNrr74T

[image]

Feel free to say or give any advice we’re novices and just trying to get it right as best we can!

Comment: @crip659 it’s a mosaic tile. Not exactly this but very similar https://www.homedepot.com/p/Daltile-LuxeCraft-White-11-in-x-12-in-x-6-35-mm-Ceramic-Picket-Mosaic-Wall-Tile-0-73-sq-ft-Each-LC1525PICKHD1P2/308999233   I have some bull nose type tiles also I could buy more for the bottom if it was better since this tile is pointy

Comment: Consider removing the cabinets before you put up the tile.  Draw a line where the bottom of the cabinets is, then remove if you can.  You'll have much more working space and won't have to twist your neck. to look up at the bottom of the cabinets.

Comment: I've done multiple kitchen backsplashes. The effort involved in removing cabinetry (and counter tops!) has never seemed remotely beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

The gaps look to be minimal. I wouldn't be concerned.

However, I do apply some fast dry latex caulking to fill gaps before tiling.
The latex allows thinset and grout to stick. Do NOT use silicone.

Be diligent when grouting to fill all gaps. Use an *unsanded*  grout for grout lines 1/8 inch or smaller.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no problem here from a tiling perspective. Even mosaic will span those small gaps without issue.

*The problem is that you have untaped drywall joints*, which can be quite flexible as they're unsupported between studs. I would assess this with light pressure at the center of the span. If it's a bit mushy, consider cutting in backing and retaping. While larger tile can handle softer substrate by adding its own stiffness, mosaic is likely to exhibit grout line cracks due to impacts.

Tile, like many things, is as much about preparation as the actual install. It's worth fixing this now.

Comment: Thanks. They seem pretty strong not much give so I’m not very concerned about it